# Having problems applying android code architecture/design patterns

Tags: android, design-patterns, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-room, code-structure

**I want to achieve the following:**

I receive a notification via FCM with a specific `id` in the data properties. I get the `id` both when my app is in foreground and in the background/closed...so far so good.
Now I want to do the following:

1. Make a volley request to e.g. `/books/id` to get the corresponding book informations.
2. Save those informations persistently in a `Room database`
3. Display them in a `RecyclerView`

***Scenario 1:***  *App with RecyclerView is in foreground:*
As soon as I receive a new `id` via the FCM notification data, I want my `RecyclerView` to append another list item with the newly fetched book informations.

***Scenario 2:*** *App is in background - notification gets clicked:*
When the notification gets clicked, the `MainActivity` with the `RecyclerView` gets loaded, showing the newly fetched book informations.

***Scenario 3:*** *App is in background - notification gets swiped away:*
After some time the notification was swiped away the user re-opens or restarts the app. The `MainActivity` with the `RecyclerView` and the newly fetched book informations is shown.

**My problem:**
I don't quite know how to structure my code to accomplish this.
I tried making the volley request inside of FCM's `onMessageReceived()` but that resulted in an error and I don't know where and how I could do that otherwise. I tested the volley request in another project and it worked there.
Currently I try to learn how to work with the Room database.

I would really appreciate if someone can give me an insight of how to accomplish something like that. I really need to get this to work soon.

**Thanks in advance! :)**

---

**EDIT 1:**
I dont't get the error inside of the `onMessageReceived` anymore. I receive the correct response with the given book `id`.
Now I want to save these informations into the `Room database` and reflect the change in my `RecyclerView`. I think I'm going to use androids `architecture components` like here:
[android architecture components example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0)

I think that's exactly what I need. However, I still don't quite understand how to deal with it and structure my code accordingly.

Comment: Can you post what error you're seeing when you make the Volley request inside `onMessageReceived()`? Let's try to solve that then think about restructuring your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't get the error anymore and updated my post accordingy. I'm still quite confused how to structure the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario 1:** You may save it in DB, or just do broadcast and save it for instance in Activity then display a list.

**Scenario 2:** You should keep all display data in DB. After click on notification when `RecyclerView` *is in background*, you should handle the intent that pass through `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` of intent-filter and put some info there to make a request and update the list.

**Scenario 3:** Finally, just do a request, save in DB, then display all in the list. This is a good approche, it takes extra time, but you always keep it updated.

Also read about efficient hot swap data with [DiffUtils](https://medium.com/mindorks/diffutils-improving-performance-of-recyclerview-102b254a9e4a)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations, I will definitely read about DiffUtils.

Comment: I am glad to read that I helped you with something. Good luck with future code implementation! :)